# Reading CSV file using BufferedReader resulting in reading alternative lines

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to read a *csv* file from my java code. using the following piece of code:

```
public void readFile() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String newLine;
    while ((newLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        newLine = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(newLine);
        lines.add(newLine);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

The output I get from the above piece of code is every alternative line [2nd, 4th, 6th lines] is read and returned by the `readLine()` method. I'm not sure why this behavior exists. Please correct me if I am missing something while reading the csv file.

Comment: Accept good answers to your previous questions. This is a reward to people that help you.

Answer (score 7):

The first time you're reading the line without processing it in the `while` loop, then you're reading it again but this time you're processing it. `readLine()` method reads a line and displaces the reader-pointer to the next line in the file. Hence, every time you use this method, the pointer will be incremented by one pointing to the next line.

This:

```
 while ((newLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        newLine = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(newLine);
        lines.add(newLine);
    }
```

Should be changed to this:

```
 while ((newLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(newLine);
        lines.add(newLine);
    }
```

Hence reading a line and processing it, without reading another line and then processing.

Comment: Thank you Mike, for pointing the problem and discrpting the problem. I have made corrections and I am seeing the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the first line in a loop body 
`newLine = br.readLine();`

Answer (score 0):

In java 8, we can easily achieve it

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
List<List<String>> dataList = br.lines()
           .map(k -> Arrays.asList(k.split(",")))
           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

outer list will have rows and inner list will have corresponding column values