# What would be a good program that includes writing data to a text or csv file and/or reading from a text or csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I am still a beginner in java we are task to create a program that includes writing data to a text or csv file and/or reading from a text or csv file.A program that can help or any modern problem. any simple idea?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be very focused, meaning it's not about a specific programming proglem. And seems to be opinion based. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Already posted solution in Java 8. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/62171055/2648257

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform this task as fast as possible, I suggest you looking at this library that handles CSV file I/O operations:
[Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Other resources at this link: https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java#CSV

For a homemade solution try to implement by yourself the logic using Java Core with BufferedReader to read a file line by line, and FileWriter for write strings to append in the file.

BufferedReader example:

```
BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathInputFile));
 while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
  // do for each row something 
  // if you use a csv get every values using split method: 
  // String[] data = row.split(",");
 } 
 csvReader.close();
```

FileWriter example:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(pathOutputFile);
 // use csvWriter.append(data) for write strings

 // If you want to use a csv structure:
 //csvWriter.append("Value1");
 //csvWriter.append(",");
 //csvWriter.append("Value2");
 //if a csv line is finished go down with \n token
 //csvWriter.append("\n");

 //when finish the write operation
 csvWriter.flush();
 csvWriter.close();
```