# Reading the csv file and storing its values ​in a 2-dimensional int array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, csv

my CSV file is called " Noteslist" it looks like this in principle, but the list goes down for more than 50 rows

MatrNr,Note
584711,40
584712,55
584713,67
584714,23
584715,89
584716,95
584717,59
584718,66
584719,81
584720,78
584721,97
584722,11
584723,17
584724,68
584725,45

i am supposed to read the CSV file and store the values into a 2 dimensional Int array. i did the first part reading the csv file, but i don't know about the second part, i really would appreciate your help.

my code so far :

public static void main(String[] args){

```
    String fileName= "Noteslist.csv";
    File file=new File(fileName);
    try {

        Scanner inputStream= new Scanner(file);

        while ( inputStream.hasNext()){

            String notesList = inputStream.next();
            String values[]=notesList.split(",");


        }

        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Hi, you can use a `List<Integer[]>` and put the readed and splitted row into an `Integer[]` of two elements, and at the end of loop put this array into list. At beginning of loop you can create `new Integer[2]`

Comment: have you resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Reading csv data and storing in to collection object. Solution already given in the below post.
Please check it out.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62171055/2648257